# What alternatives are there to Protegè to help drafting an ontology?

Tags: rdf, ontology, protege

I am using Protegè to model a human drug domain: molecules, medicines, producers, related codes, etc.

Would there be some easier form of GUI in which I could draw classes, object and data properties graphically as nodes, edges and labels?

Comment: there are indeed alternatives, like chowlk, graphol etc. - if those are easier, depends on you. And indeed this is not a question for Stackoverflow

Comment: Thank you very much. I am sorry of the question was not fit for SO but could you be so kind to explain why so that avoid mistakes such ss this in the future? I had this in mind which I read some time ago in the "Which questions are ok on SO" "software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development." and believed mine fit this description. Again thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Protégé](https://protege.stanford.edu/) is a free and open source ontology editor. However, there are many other alternatives to Protégé to develop an ontology. These are mentioned below.

1. The [PoolParty](https://www.poolparty.biz/) Semantic Suite based on the SKOS (Simple Knowledge Organization System), ontologies, and Linked Data principles, is an enterprises knowledge management system that uses standards-based technologies as defined by W3C. It transforms data into RDF graph that can be queried using SPARQL query language.
2. The [KAON](http://kaon2.semanticweb.org/) (Karlsruhe ontology) is an ontology infrastructure offering reasoning support for OWL ontologies.
3. The [NeOn](http://neon-toolkit.org/wiki/Main_Page.html) Toolkit which is based on the Eclipse platform is an open source, multi-platform ontology editor, which supports the development of ontologies in F-Logic and OWL/RDF. It provides ontology engineering activities such as Annotation and Documentation, Modularization and Customization, Reuse, Ontology Evolution, Translation, etc.
4. [OntoUML](https://ontouml.org/ontouml/) which is built as an UML extension is based on the Unified Foundational Ontology (UFO) and is an ontologically well-founded language for Ontology-driven Conceptual Modeling.